# HTML video element playing properly in local dev environment, but won't show in Netlify production deploy

Tags: video, deployment, html5-video, media-player, netlify

I have a video on my site that I'm just storing as a static asset and rendering on the page with HTML like so:

```
<video
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  autoPlay
  loop
  muted
>
  <source src='src/assets/demo.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

This video plays exactly as expected when I run my development server on localhost, but when I deploy up to production on Netlify, the video does not render at all. When I inspect the page, it sees an empty video element there with the description "Unable to play video." When I check the network tab, the video comes through with a code 206. My Netlify app is being built and deployed automatically from the Github repo.

I've tried changing the codec from .mov to .mp4 as well as compressing it, but that hasn't worked. I've displayed videos in this way on other projects before with no problem, although those were deployed with GitHub Pages rather than with Netlify. Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the issue by importing the video rather than supplying the direct path to the source as I did in the above code.

```
import demo from '../../../../assets/demo.mp4';

<video
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  autoPlay
  loop
  muted
>
  <source src={demo} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```